# Select specific node in XML to HtmlEntityDecode (unescape) in Classic ASP

Tags: xml, vbscript, asp-classic

I get a soap response that gives me XML that looks like this (all of the information from the web service is given in a string format and put into the  node):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<GetAllBookingsResponse xmlns="http://DEA.EMS.API.Web.Service/">
<GetAllBookingsResult>&lt
    ;Bookings&gt;
      &lt;Data&gt;
        &lt;BookingDate&gt;2015-04-09T00:00:00&lt;/BookingDate&gt;
    &lt;/Data&gt;
    &lt;/Bookings&gt;
</GetAllBookingsResult>
</GetAllBookingsResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I was using Replace to replace the `&lt;` and `&gt;` with the appropriate < and > however I was informed that's not the best method to do that.

I found HtmlEntityDecode - but I cannot seem to select the appropriate node to use that function on the string.

My code looks like this:

```
<%
Dim objXMLHTTP : set objXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

Dim strRequest, strResult, strFunction, strURL, strNamespace

'URL to SOAP namespace and connection URL
strNamespace = "http://DEA.EMS.API.Web.Service/"
strURL = "http://myserver/EMSAPI/"

'function you want to call
strFunction = "GetBuildings"
'strFunction = "test" 'no parameters required

strRequest ="<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" &_
      "<soap:Envelope" &_
      " xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""" &_
      " xmlns:api=""http://127.0.0.1/Integrics/Enswitch/API""" &_
      " xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema""" &_
      " xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">" &_
        "<soap:Body>" &_
                "<GetBuildings xmlns=""http://DEA.EMS.API.Web.Service/"">" &_
                    "<UserName>Myusername</UserName>" &_
                    "<Password>mypassword</Password>" &_
                "</GetBuildings>" &_
        "</soap:Body>" &_
      "</soap:Envelope>"


objXMLHTTP.open "POST", ""& strURL &"", True

objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(strRequest) 
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", strNamespace & strFunction


'send the request and capture the result
objXMLHTTP.send(strRequest)

'Set a timer to wait for response
set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 t1 = timer()
 sleep(1)
 t2 = timer()
 response.write "waited "& t2-t1 &" secs"

 function sleep(seconds)
    if seconds>=1 then shell.popup "pausing",seconds,"pause",64
 end function


strResult = objXMLHTTP.responseText
'strResult = Replace(strResult, "&lt;", "<")
'strResult = Replace(strResult, "&gt;", ">")


'display the XML
response.write strResult

%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hanny,

I've recently had to do a similar thing on an old Classic ASP site. Here's a function that I wrote to handle my specific case, but adapted to yours:

```
Function xmlNodeReturn(inXMLStr, NodePattern)
    'Err will help us detect failure to find the correct Node in the XMLResponse
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim xmlDoc, rtnHolder

    'Need to work with XML Object to properly access the data contained
    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    xmlDoc.async = false
    xmlDoc.loadXML inXMLStr

    'Identify Parent and Target Node for which you need data and place it's text contents in a holder...
    rtnHolder = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode(NodePattern).text
    Set xmlDoc = Nothing

    'If the identified node is NOT found Err will result...
    If Err <> 0 Then
        rtnHolder = False
        Err.Clear
    End If
    xmlNodeReturn = rtnHolder
End Function

getResults = xmlNodeReturn(strResult, "//GetAllBookingsResponse/GetAllBookingsResult")
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Optionally, you could just remove all the newlines and use a Regular Expression, or VBScript Mid(string,start[,length]) to get the contents.

```
Function RegExpReturnPart(ValTest, PartToReturn, ContentBody)
    Dim regEx, theMatches, theMatch
    Set regEx = New RegExp
    regEx.Pattern = ValTest
    regEx.IgnoreCase = True

    ContentBody = Replace(ContentBody, vbNewline, "[NEWLINE]")

    Set theMatches = regEx.Execute(ContentBody)

    'This is admittedly sloppy, but I assume you have one result that you care about
    If theMatches.Count > 0 Then
        RegExpReturnPart = Replace(theMatches(0).SubMatches(PartToReturn - 1), "[NEWLINE]", vbNewLine)
    Else
        RegExpReturnPart = "NOT RETURNED"
    End If
    Set regEx = Nothing
End Function

getResults = RegExpReturnPart("<GetAllBookingsResult>(.*)</GetAllBookingsResult>", "$1", strResult)
```

Hope one of these is helpful.